# Do I still need a Land valuation document for Visa proceedings in this Regard?

Tags: canada, standard-visitor-visas, nigerian-citizens

Is deed of Gift OKAY for a visa application to Canada, to show Ties to Nigeria , or Do i still need Show added property Valuation documents.

This Question is subject to My visa application for Canada, Attached to my documents for my Tourist visas, I included the following

- Travel History
- Deed of Gift (Certified by Lawyers in my home country)
- Job offer / Leave Approval Letter
- Sworn Affidavits of Claims of Business and Business Registration Documents
- Purpose of Visit (Conference, its a free conference in the Energy sector)
- Bank statement of 60,000 CAD equivalient in total savings etc.

Kindly advice if this is good for an application for a visit visa for Canada or do I need to present other documentation as well?

Comment: An invitation to attend the conference from the organisers would be a good idea

Comment: @Traveller, I have that. I included that as well As well as other documentation enlisted here.

Comment: I have no idea what ‘ Sworn Affidavits of Claims of Business’ could be. Do they perhaps constitute evidence that the business is a profitable going concern that pays you an income and requires your ongoing presence in Nigeria?

Comment: @Traveller, yes.

Answer (score 2):

There are no hard and fast rules about what constitutes evidence of ties to your home country. If a deed of gift establishes your ownership of the land, then that is enough to show that you own land. Note that owning land is not actually a very strong time to your country - people can and do own land while living in a completely different country. However it is better than not owning land. More evidence is always better than less evidence (as long as it's genuine).